# Streamreader does not work when I close HttpWebResponse early

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse, streamreader

```
Uri targetUri = new Uri(targetURL);    
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
response.Close();
```

Why does the above code work fine but the following does not?
Notice I close response early in the following code.

```
Uri targetUri = new Uri(targetURL);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
response.Close();
string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Closing the response closes the response stream as well... so the `StreamReader` no longer has anything to read from.

From the documentation for [`WebResponse.Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.close.aspx):

> The Close method cleans up the
>   resources used by a WebResponse and
>   closes the underlying stream by
>   calling the Stream.Close method.

Answer (score 0):

Your reader was initialized with the stream from the response, so it is using it.

If you close the response stream, the reader no longer has a working underlying stream to read from.